# Javascript nullish coalescing chained with "or"

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, operators

I'm making use of Javascript's "??" operator to assign a default value when the variable is undefined along with "||" when I don't want an undefined value or 0.

For example, the following will prefer "a" when defined or resort to "b".
Then it would prefer 1 when the coalesced value was undefined or 0:

```
var a, b;
console.log((a ?? b) || 1); // prints "1"
```

However, the following tweak presents a compilation error.
I'd expect it to either print "1" or "undefined" depending on operation precedence:

```
var a, b;
console.log(a ?? b || 1); // Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"
```

Lastly, this compiles and runs but with the caveat that "0" would be an accepted value:

```
var a, b;
console.log(a ?? b ?? 1); // prints "1"
```

What's the nuance that I'm missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why JavaScript forbids combining Nullish operator (`??`) with And (`&&`), OR (`||`) operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69580087/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#no_chaining_with_and_or_or_operators), you can't chain the nullish coalescing operator with AND or OR:

MDN:

> It is not possible to combine both the AND (&&) and OR operators (||) directly with ??. A SyntaxError will be thrown in such cases.

```
null || undefined ?? "foo"; // raises a SyntaxError
true || undefined ?? "foo"; // raises a SyntaxError
```

> However, providing parenthesis to explicitly indicate precedence is correct:

```
(null || undefined) ?? "foo"; // returns "foo"
```

I found this [blog post](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-use-nullish-coalescing-with-logical-and-or-or-operators-in-javascript) a helpful resource in thinking through why.

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately the minifer I use strips the parentheses in this case, another problem for another day.

Comment: @heyufool1 Definitely a bug, yeah